# Find the probability distribution for the random variable the smaller or equal number when two ordinary dice are thrown?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

P(X=n)=
\begin{cases}
    \frac{11}{36}&n=1\\\
    \frac{ 9}{36}&n=2\\\
    \frac{ 7}{36}&n=3\\\
    \frac{ 5}{36}&n=4\\\
    \frac{ 3}{36}&n=5\\\
    \frac{ 1}{36}&n=6\\\
  \end{cases}
I have tried in this manner? is it correct?

Comment: This looks fine to me

Comment: Ok thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your obtained result is correct.

The probability that $n=k$, $1<=k<=6$ is the smaller or equal number, would be $\frac {2(6-k)+1}{36}=\frac {13-2k}{36}$.

Comment: This isn't really an answer; it would be better to post it as a comment. Alternatively, edit your answer to add some insights.

Comment: Alright let me edit it

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta thanks